# Using Proximity Alerts with Google Maps activity

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I use proximity alerts on my Google Maps activity?
This proximity alerts are located within a certain radius that I already specified earlier.

```
public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener 
{ 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        int lat = (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6); 
        int lng = (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1E6); 
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);    
        mapController.animateTo(point); // mapController.setCenter(point) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code of what you have done?

Comment: I just finished writing a program to display google maps.

Comment: you will need to edit your question and post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any line of code it's really difficult to suggest you anything else than reading the following tutorial: [Android Proximity Alerts Tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-proximity-alerts-tutorial.html).
The key part of it is the [LocationManager.addProximityAlert()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert%28double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method, which

> Sets a proximity alert for the location given by the position (latitude, longitude) and the given radius. When the device detects that it has entered or exited the area surrounding the location, the given PendingIntent will be used to create an Intent to be fired.

Answer (score -1):

This is the code I used for setting proximity alert on my app:

```
LocationManager lm=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, expiration, intent);
```